# "His mathematics are weak" - grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar, verbs, subject-verb-agreement

We were studying Nouns today and certain words related to different subjects came which seem to be plural but are actually singular like *Mathematics, Ethics, Physics etc* and so, we must a singular verb with them..

But then came one sentence,

> His mathematics **are** weak.

Anyone who can clear whether this sentence is correct or not? And if it is then what possibly is the reason?

Comment: Can you elaborate what "mathematics" means in your context?